# How to understand the "NTSTATUS", "NT_SUCCESS" typedef in windows ddk?

Tags: c, driver, wdk

Two questions:

1.

In "ntdef.h" the **NTSTATUS** is defined as follow:

```
typedef __success(return >= 0) LONG NTSTATUS;
```

what the hell is the "__success(return >= 0)"?

2.

In "ntstatus.h", **STATUS_SUCCESS** is defined to 0.

```
#define STATUS_SUCCESS   ((NTSTATUS)0x00000000L) // ntsubauth
```

But the **NT_SUCCESS** macro in "ntdef.h" is:

```
#define NT_SUCCESS(Status) (((NTSTATUS)(Status)) >= 0)
```

Shouldn't it be "Status == 0" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

__success is an "Advanced Annotation" defined in SpecStrings_strict.h, which defines it as follows.

```
*  __success(expr) T f() :  indicates whether function f succeeded or
*  not. If  is true at exit, all the function's guarantees (as given
*  by other annotations) must hold. If  is false at exit, the caller
*  should not expect any of the function's guarantees to hold. If not used,
*  the function must always satisfy its guarantees. Added automatically to
*  functions that indicate success in standard ways, such as by returning an
*  HRESULT.
```

The reason that `NT_SUCCESS` doesn't do a strict test against `STATUS_SUCCESS (0)` is probably that other codes like `STATUS_PENDING` aren't actually failures.

Answer (score 3):

The fragment `__success(return >= 0)` is a SAL annotation, which gives a clue to the PreFast tool about what the intended semantics of the macro are. This is used to do static analysis and identify potential bugs.

The `NT_SUCCESS` macro tests for `>= 0` because there are success codes other than `STATUS_SUCCESS`. Some success codes include extra information about the outcome of the operation, although at the moment I can only think of `S_FALSE`, which notifies the caller that the operation succeeded, but the result was false. As a rule, success codes are equal to or greater than zero, and failure codes are less than zero.

[Strictly speaking, `S_FALSE` is an `HRESULT`, not an `NT_STATUS`, though the two types have the same size and similar conventions.]

Answer (score 2):

__success is described nicely in *Annotating for __success()* article by Michael Fourre ([archived link](http://web.archive.org/web/20110119004951/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/staticdrivertools/archive/2008/11/06/annotating-for-success.aspx)).

Answer to 2 is No, all positive codes are non-failures. They may mean something other than OK though.