# Cannot understand this c++ typedef

Tags: c++, typedef

I am not really sure how to read this code:

```
typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* QUERYINFORMATIONPROCESS)(
  IN   HANDLE ProcessHandle,
  IN   PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass,
  OUT  PVOID ProcessInformation,
  IN   ULONG ProcessInformationLength,
  OUT  PULONG ReturnLength OPTIONAL
  );
```

Is `NTSTATUS` or `QUERYINFORMATIONPROCESS` the name of the `typedef`? And, if so,  what is the actual type? Is this a function pointer type? The usage is this:

```
QUERYINFORMATIONPROCESS QueryInformationProcess =
    (QUERYINFORMATIONPROCESS)GetProcAddress(
    hDll, "NtQueryInformationProcess");

  if (QueryInformationProcess)
  {
    NTSTATUS ntStatus = QueryInformationProcess(
      processInformation.hProcess,
      PROCESSINFOCLASS::ProcessBasicInformation,
      &pbi, sizeof(pbi), &uLength);
  […]
```

This comes from a the "C++ Multithreading Cookbook", which does not explain this piece of code. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing it without the Microsoft macros, it's

```
typedef NTSTATUS (*QUERYINFORMATIONPROCESS)(
  HANDLE ProcessHandle,
  PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass,
  PVOID ProcessInformation,
  ULONG ProcessInformationLength,
  PULONG ReturnLength
  );
```

which is a function pointer type called "QUERYINFORMATIONPROCESS".

Specifically, it's a pointer to [NtQueryInformationProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280(v=vs.85).aspx), which needs to be loaded from a DLL.

(And it appears the author of your book is having spelling problems.)

Comment: I see, the usage of the NTAPI, IN, OUT is the fact that this is MS macro! Thank you so much! and yes! the author of the book does have spelling problems :)

Answer (score 4):

```
typedef NTSTATUS(NTAPI* QUERYINFORMATIONPROCESS)(
  IN    HANDLE ProcessHandle,
  IN    PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass,
  OUT  PVOID ProcessInformation,
  IN    ULONG ProcessInformationLength,
  OUT  PULONG ReturnLength OPTIONAL
  );
```

The hard part here is that this is a function pointer:

When declaring a function pointer, to distinguish it from a function returning a pointer, we need parenthesis around it's name:

```
(*QUERYINFORMATIONPROCESS)
```

The NTAPI before the pointer is there to tell the compiler the calling convention (how arguments are passed [registers, on stack, order of arguments], how the cleanup of arguments is done, etc).

The remaining stuff is just the return type (`NTSTATUS`) and the arguments to the function.

A much simpler example is:

```
 typedef int (*funcptr)(int x);
```

Now, that's relatively easy to see that it's a function returning `int`, and it's a pointer to the function, and it's taking one argument that is `int x`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Could you expand a little bit on what the NTAPI is doing there? In addition what are the IN/OUT doing there?

Comment: What do you want to know. It's defining the calling convention for the Windows NT system calls - which is different from "standard" C calling convention - and only for 32-bit systems. In 64-bit machines, it turns into "nothing" (or at least, using a calling convention will have no effect, since there is only one calling convention for normal functions)

Comment: I see, so if I were to rewrite this on an operating system like Linux I would not need the IN/OUT or NTAPI, this is a declaration syntax typical of Windows? - Thank you!

Comment: Yes, and the calls to fetch something from a shared library, and the query for processes is completely and utterly different...

Comment: In other words, there is NOTHING useful on the page of code you just posted.

Answer (score 2):

There is a rule which helps reading such elaborate type definitions called the [Clockwise/Spiral](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) rule. The rule is a three step algorithm, citing the original article the steps are:

1. Starting with the unknown element, move in a spiral/clockwise direction; when ecountering the following elements replace them with the corresponding english statements:

   - [X] or [] => Array X size of... or Array undefined size of...
   - (type1, type2) => function passing type1 and type2 returning...
   - * => pointer(s) to...
2. Keep doing this in a spiral/clockwise direction until all tokens have been covered.
3. Always resolve anything in parenthesis first!

It is generally useful to know which identifier corresponds to a type in order to identify unknown elements (there may be multiple such elements). In your case - knowing that all of (`NTSTATUS`, `NTAPI`, `HANDLE`, `PROCESSINFOCLASS`, `PVOID`, `ULONG`, `PULONG`) are types.

The article provides useful examples on applying the rule.

Besides, I've found an image in Google which illustrates the rule:
[image: Applying the spiral/clockwise rule]

Identify unknown elements:

- `void` is a type
- `signal`, hmm, looks like an unknown element. Besides, it is
  located to the right of the asterisk and cannot be anything but an variable/typedef name as far as I am concerned
- `int`, `void` - types
- `fp`, the second unknown element (remember, I've mentioned earlier that there can be multiple unknown elements)
- `int`, `int` - types

Now start by applying the rule from the leftmost unknown element, namely `signal`:

1. Move from `signal` to the right and encounter the first opening parenthesis: `signal` is a function taking an `int` and something elaborate
2. Let's analyze the second unknown element `fp` which is also the second argument to `signal`. Move in a clockwise spiral from `fp` and encounter the closing parenthesis and then the asterisk: `fp` is a pointer to something.
3. Continue moving from `*fp` and encounter the opening parenthesis: `fp` is a pointer to a function taking an `int` and returning something.
4. Continue moving and encounter `void`: `fp` is a pointer to a function taking an `int` and returning `void`.
5. Now that we've decoded the second argument to `signal`: `signal` is a function taking an `int, and a pointer to a function taking an`int`and returning`void`
6. Continue moving from `signal(` and encounter the asterisk: `signal` is a function returning a pointer to...
7. Continue moving from `(*` and encounter the rightmost opening parenthesis: `signal` is a function (I'm omitting the arguments here) returning a pointer to a function taking an `int`
8. Finally, encounter `void`: `signal` is a function (I'm omitting the arguments here) returning a pointer to a function taking an `int` and returning `void`.

P.S. The typedef from your question can be written in modern C++ with the `using` declaration:

```
using QUERYINFORMATIONPROCESS = NTSTATUS(NTAPI*)(
  IN   HANDLE ProcessHandle,
  IN   PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass,
  OUT  PVOID ProcessInformation,
  IN   ULONG ProcessInformationLength,
  OUT  PULONG ReturnLength OPTIONAL
  );
```

It does not change much, but the `typedef-name` there is more separated from the actual definition and makes it a bit more readable. When writing new code, consider using `using` instead of `typedef` :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's a typedef on a pointer to a function, called QUERYINFORMATIONPROCESS. this function take 5 parameters, and return a NTSTATUS.

Answer (score 1):

That would a function pointer `typedef`, which defines the type `QUERYINFORMATIONPROCESS` as an alias for this type:

```
NTSTATUS(NTAPI*)(
  IN   HANDLE ProcessHandle,
  IN   PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass,
  OUT  PVOID ProcessInformation,
  IN   ULONG ProcessInformationLength,
  OUT  PULONG ReturnLength OPTIONAL
  );
```

When used as in the example,

```
QUERYINFORMATIONPROCESS QueryInformationProcess =
    (QUERYINFORMATIONPROCESS)GetProcAddress(
    hDll, "NtQueryInformationProcess");
```

it expands into something like this:

```
NTSTATUS(NTAPI* QueryInformationProcess)(
  IN   HANDLE ProcessHandle,
  IN   PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass,
  OUT  PVOID ProcessInformation,
  IN   ULONG ProcessInformationLength,
  OUT  PULONG ReturnLength OPTIONAL
  ) = 
    (NTSTATUS(NTAPI*)(
      IN    HANDLE ProcessHandle,
      IN    PROCESSINFOCLASS ProcessInformationClass,
      OUT  PVOID ProcessInformation,
      IN    ULONG ProcessInformationLength,
      OUT  PULONG ReturnLength OPTIONAL
    ))GetProcAddress(hDll, "NtQueryInformationProcess");
```

(Not 100% sure if that's the correct expansion, I find function pointers awkward in general.)

Function pointer typedefs are used because function pointer syntax is *really* awkward in and of itself, while function pointer aliases like that use the standard syntax.

For more information on function pointers, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4295495/5386374).

---

Moreover, it's a pointer to a Windows function, which uses standard Windows identifiers (NTSTATUS, NTAPI, IN, OUT, HANDLE, PROCESSINFOCLASS, PVOID, ULONG, and PULONG).

According to Windows files, these identifiers are:

```
// ntdef.h
typedef __success(return >= 0) LONG NTSTATUS;
// See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378622/how-to-understand-the-ntstatus-nt-success-typedef-in-windows-ddk

// WinNT.h
#define NTAPI __stdcall
// __stdcall is a Windows calling convention, used by Visual Studio when compiling Windows code.

typedef void *PVOID;

#ifdef STRICT
    typedef void *HANDLE;
    #if 0 && (_MSC_VER > 1000)
        #define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__; typedef struct name##__ *name
    #else
        #define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__{int unused;}; typedef struct name##__ *name
    #endif
#else
    typedef PVOID HANDLE;
    #define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) typedef HANDLE name
#endif


// WinDef.h
typedef unsigned long ULONG;
typedef ULONG *PULONG;

#ifndef IN
    #define IN
#endif

#ifndef OUT
    #define OUT
#endif
```

IN and OUT are used as programmer aids, while the types are to give programmers a consistent interface.  Not entirely sure about `PROCESSINFOCLASS`; it seems to be defined in `ntdll.dll`, along with `NtQueryInformationProcess` itself.  According to [this MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42975089-ce2f-4fbe-b1bc-a94a482444bd/visual-studio-debugger-keeps-processes-to-next-session-programatically-how-to-detach-on-process?forum=vsx), it's defined as follows:

```
private enum PROCESSINFOCLASS : int
{
  ProcessBasicInformation = 0,
  ProcessQuotaLimits,
  ProcessIoCounters,
  ProcessVmCounters,
  ProcessTimes,
  ProcessBasePriority,
  ProcessRaisePriority,
  ProcessDebugPort,
  ProcessExceptionPort,
  ProcessAccessToken,
  ProcessLdtInformation,
  ProcessLdtSize,
  ProcessDefaultHardErrorMode,
  ProcessIoPortHandlers, // Note: this is kernel mode only
  ProcessPooledUsageAndLimits,
  ProcessWorkingSetWatch,
  ProcessUserModeIOPL,
  ProcessEnableAlignmentFaultFixup,
  ProcessPriorityClass,
  ProcessWx86Information,
  ProcessHandleCount,
  ProcessAffinityMask,
  ProcessPriorityBoost,
  MaxProcessInfoClass
} ;
```

This appears to be outdated, but [this site](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ntdll/PROCESSINFOCLASS.html) seems to have a more recent version, which appears to be consistent with [official MS NtQueryInformationProcess() documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Hope this helps.